# How to produce nil property assignments during a CAKeyframeAnimation?

Tags: core-animation

I assumed that adding an `NSNull` instance to the `CAKeyframeAnimation`'s `values` array would result in a `nil` value being assigned to the property at the appropriate time. (I'm using `kCAAnimationDiscrete` to step through a sequence of values.)

```
NSMutableArray *keyframeValues = [NSMutableArray array];
...
[keyframeValues addObject:[NSNull null]];
```

But what I get is the actual `NSNull` reference in the property, which I have to explicitly test for and filter out:

```
- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    if (self.myProp == (id)[NSNull null]) ...
```

I can deal with this, of course, but it looks a little weird, since the `NSNull` is not type-compatible with the property. I just expected CAKeyframeAnimation to translate this back to `nil` and am wondering if there is something I'm doing wrong or if this is a bug (or at least a bit surprising).